# Find the number of the fixed point of $G^n$ if we define $G(x)=4x(1-x)$ and $G:[0,1] \to [0,1]$

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Let $G:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ and $G(x)=4x(1-x)$.

Find the number of the fixed points of $G^n$ with $n \geq 1$.

It is easy to find the number of the fixed points if $n=1,2$, or even $3$ using equation $G(x)=x$. But I don't know how to calculate for the general case n. If someone can help me with this, it would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Set $x = \sin^2 \theta$ ..

Comment: Hint: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obbj3mpgeq

Comment: Sorry, does $G^n$ means $G$ to the $n$th iteration or $G$ to the $n$th power?

Comment: @JetfiRex:In dynamical systems $F^n$ more often than not denotes the composition of the map $F$ with itself $n$ times. $F^0$ being the identity map

Comment: @AlpUzman thanks for the visualization. From the graph I can guess the number of fixed points should be $2^n$ right? But how to state that formally?

Comment: @r9m thanks for the hints. I am thinking on it.

Comment: @TakatoshiRyu Yes; some version of the map r9m gives a topological conjugacy between the two maps; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Finding_cycles_of_any_length_when_r_=_4

Comment: @r9m I figured it out. So, $\theta$ should be in the range $[0,\pi)$ right? Because if we include $\pi$ we will have 3 roots, for example in the first case $G(x)=x$ means $\sin (2x)=\sin (x)$. Please give a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @AlpUzman thanks for the help. Using r9m's hint I can prove it formally.

Comment: @TakatoshiRyu $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$, we want a unique solution to $x = \sin^2 \theta$ .. so that counting fixed points of $G^n(x)$ is reduced to counting solutions of $\sin^2(2^n\theta) = \sin^2 \theta$ .. (otherwise we might be overcounting?)